# Why image stretch over in SwiftUI though it is limited 44x44?

Tags: swiftui

Have this image:

```swift
HStack {
    if holeTop != nil {
        Image(uiImage: holeTop!).frame(width: 44, height: 44)
    } else {
```

Ant it is not inside 44x44 but that over whole screen and even more. Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify your code as below:

```
 Image(uiImage: holeTop!)
    .resizable()
    .frame(width: 44, height: 44)
```